# IE: ‘nodeType’ is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having this issue on my website in IE (6,7,8):

> ‘nodeType’ is null or not an object

The error refers to "f.nodeType" property. Basically f is undefined, so the issue is before, but I cannot fix it.

(from IE developer toolbar debug it appears to be this line that is throwing the error)
(`autocolumn.min.js line 13` expanded below for readability)

Page is at http://www.donatellabernardi.ch/drupal

```
function split($putInHere,$pullOutHere,$parentColumn,height){
  if($pullOutHere.children().length){
    $cloneMe=$pullOutHere.children(":first");
    $clone=$cloneMe.clone(true);
    if($clone.attr("nodeType")==1&&!$clone.hasClass("dontend")){
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Chokes on

      $putInHere.append($clone);
      if($clone.is("img")&&$parentColumn.height()<height+20){
        $cloneMe.remove();
      }else if(!$cloneMe.hasClass("dontsplit")&&$parentColumn.height()<height+20){
        $cloneMe.remove();
      }else if($clone.is("img")||$cloneMe.hasClass("dontsplit")){
        $clone.remove();
      }else{
        $clone.empty();
        if(!columnize($clone,$cloneMe,$parentColumn,height)){
          if($cloneMe.children().length){
            split($clone,$cloneMe,$parentColumn,height);
          }
        }
        if($clone.get(0).childNodes.length==0){
          $clone.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @scunliffe. Thanks for editing. How did you expand Javascript ? are you using a specific software or you did it manually ? thanks

Comment: I don't know jquery well enough to know if this:
$clone.attr("nodeType")
should be $clone.nodeType-

but nodeType is not an attr in ordinary javascript/dom..

Comment: kennebec: jQuery's `attr` method doesn't always deal with attributes. Sometimes it deals with properties, and sometimes it deals with attributes, depending on the property/attribute being accessed. Getting to the heart of exactly what it is supposed to do seems to have been beyond whoever documented it in the jQuery docs.

Comment: @Patrick - no problem on the edits, as for the formatting I have a tool for that ;-) but all it does is asks Firefox for the string value of the function... and it auto formats it.

Comment: Update: $clone = $cloneMe.clone(true); the cloning function is causing the issue (probably because I'm not using the most recent version of jQuery (but I cannot upgrade, since I'm using Drupal)

Comment: The function works 3 times, so it is not a syntax error for IE... some other reason.

Comment: This is also an interesting error message I got in Chrome: 
"Break on ErrorCopy
Permission denied to access property 'parentNode' from a non-chrome context" .. it keeps working anyway

Comment: I'm really wondering why they are using global variables `$clone` and `$cloneMe` here… I don't think this will improve something, but what happens when you put `var` in front of the 3rd and 4th line in the shown source code?

Comment: In Chrome, I get some other errors, that probably are not related to your problem, but *may* cause other issues: 1. There's this in your main page: `…cript" /></script></script>` (l. 71), causing an error and a warning. 2. “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )” in autocolumn.js, l. 43: after `removeID:true`, you should first close your object with an `}`. 3. “Uncaught TypeError: Object `#<an Object>` has no method 'columnize'” in main.js, l. 62.

Comment: About the JS formatting tool: I don't know what scunliffe used, but http://jsbeautifier.org/ does do the job.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I've added var. It is the same. I dunno how about the code, it is a jQuery plugin I've downloaded.

Comment: ok, I've fixed the first two (how comes Firebug is not that detailed such as Chrome debugger). The third one, not sure what is about. I don't get that error with Chrome debugger. In any case, I still get the same javascript error in IE.

Comment: I don't get this error message in IE 8 in IE 8 Standards Mode; in Compatibility Mode, I get the message "Please upgrade your Internet Explorer, or download a modern web browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "Firebug lite" Bookmarklet (you can get it here: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite ), I could narrow down the place where the error actually is being thrown.

It seems that the root of the problem is not in the code that you've extracted, but in jQuery itself.

I noticed that you're using jQuery version 1.2.6. The problem is the clone-method of that version. This results in an error in this line of your posted code:

```
$clone=$cloneMe.clone(true);
```

I could give you more details, where exactly the error happens, but I don't think that this will solve your problem. Anyway it's not a good idea to build a workaround for the flawed jQuery-code. I'd rather recommend to try a more recent version of jQuery (after a quick glance I saw that there the clone-method is implemented differently) and have a look if that solves your problem.

**EDIT:** 
Sorry, it's not this line

```
$clone=$cloneMe.clone(true);
```

but this line:

```
$cache.append($(this).children().clone(true));
```

(line 42 in the autocolumn.js)

Comment: ok thanks, the issue is that I cannot upgrade jQuery because Drupal doesn't support it. Should I consider to use 2 jquery versions (I not this is not efficient solution, but it might be a reasonable one).

Answer (score 0):

What happens, if you use `$clone.get(0).nodeType === 1` instead?

It's recommended to use the strict equals operator `===` instead of `==`, if the type of the value is known and no implicit conversion is needed. The strict equals operator should also work even if `nodeType` would be undefined, null or "not an object"

`.get(0)` probably is not necessary. I just wanted to make sure to work on the Element directly and not over the jQuery-Instance.

Comment: hi, it is the same, same error message. Anyway it works then, what I want to remove is the annoying error message in IE