# Jquery Tool tip in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to implement a tooltip with varied content but simply not displayed. and get an error on this line  in the js jQuery:

```
if ( targetElem.nodeType === 9 ) {
        targetWidth = target.width();
        targetHeight = target.height();
        basePosition = { top: 0, left: 0 };
    // TODO: use $.isWindow() in 1.9
    }
```

My code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MyInput").tooltip({
                content: function (response) {
                    return "Hi";
                },
                open: function () {
                    $(this).tooltip("widget").stop(false, true).hide().slideDown("fast");
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).tooltip("widget").stop(false, true).show().slideUp("fast");
                }
            }).tooltip("widget").addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        });
    </script>
```

Input

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Table1.Id, new { @readonly = "readonly", id = "MyInput" })
```

what is wrong with the code?

update

something is wrong with the jQuery UI plugin, better switch to another plugin "QTIP" and this worked well.

thanks!

Comment: most probably you have incorrect selector, are you sure that here is element like `<input type="text" id='MyInput' >` ?

Comment: the error says nodeType is null or this by defining  and my input text is this: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Table1.Id, new { @readonly = "readonly", id = "MyInput" }) . in html is <input  id="MyInput" name="table.Id" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="3" />

Comment: refer this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022686/ie-nodetype-is-null-or-not-an-object